# Java JPA Mapping part of an Embedded Id

Tags: java, jpa

I am using Java SE 8 & Java EE 8, and upgrading past this is not an option for the moment.

I have two tables in a database.  Lets say one is Employee and the other is Department.  Employee has and embedded id.

```
EmployeeId {
    Name:String
    Building:String
}

Employee {
   @EmbeddedId
   EmployeeID id;
  
   // .. more stuff ..
}
```

Department has a Map of Employees in it.

```
Department {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "employees", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
                     @JoinColumn(name = "department", referencedColumnName = "department")})
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name", updatable = false)
    private Map<String, Employee> employees;
     
}
```

My question is whether, or not, this is correct, and if it is not correct, how would I accomplish this?  I am trying to set the map's key to Employee.EmployeeID.name.  This mapping is only for lookup/reference, so it doesn't need to be updateable.

Thank you in advance.

Update: when deploying, I get the follow message in the log:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Mapjava.lang.Stringcom.entities.Employees
```

All the classes exist except not merged together like java.util.Mapjava.lang.Stringcom.entities.Employees.

---

**08/03/2021 6:17 PM EST UPDATE:**
Here is a trimmed version of the classes involved.  I trimmed it for brevity.  Originally, I was trying to keep the class definitions simple to excess information not needed for the problem.

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeePK 
        implements Serializable 
{

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 15)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "building")
    private String building;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "department")
    private String department;

    // constructors, getters, setters, and other methods...

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee 
        implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected EmployeePK employeePK;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String nickname;

    // some other columns...

    // constructors, getters, setters, and other methods...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@XmlRootElement
public class Department 
        implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String address;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String departmentNickname;
    
    @EmbeddedId
    protected DepartmentPK departmentPK; // not shown here because it is not relavent.


    //
    // problem mapping it compiles & will deploy but throws a 
    // java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Mapjava.lang.Stringcom.entities.Employee
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "employees", 
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name"),
                     @JoinColumn(name = "department", referencedColumnName = "department")}
    )
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name", updatable = false)
    @Column(table="employees")
    private Map<String, Employee> employees;
    //
    // END OF PROBLEM MAPPING

    // constructors, getters, setters, and other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a new class called EmployeeID which is your composite primary key.

```
@Embeddable

public class EmployeeID {
  String Name
  String Building 

}
```

The Embeddable annotation means this class is a composite key.

Then define your Employee Table, and include the Embedded Composite key and give it the @EmbededID annotation.

```
class Employee {
 @EmbededID
 EmployeeID

// .. more stuff ..

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have made myself clear. EmployeeID is a separate class. I just wrote it like that in as pseudo-code. I want to know how to map just the name of the EmployeeID as the key.

Comment: Then @EmbededID would solve your problem :) .

Comment: When I deploy the war file, I get the following warning in Payara:<BR>

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.Mapjava.lang.Stringcom.entities.Employees

All the classes exist except not merged together like java.util.Mapjava.lang.Stringcom.entities.Employees.

Comment: Can you provide more information related to the class.

Comment: I just updated the original post with the classes.